# Bibliography in PHP with CSL

Tags: php, bibtex, bibliography, csl

I am trying to display a bibliography in PHP and allowing the use of [CSL](http://citationstyles.org/) to format it, but am coming up short of good examples of how to implement it. Basically, I am looking for a library or script which can take a bibliography, in the form of Bibtex or JSON or similar, and output it as HTML through PHP.

Formatting with CSL, through for example [citeproc-php](https://github.com/seboettg/citeproc-php), would accomodate a vast variety of output styles. Does anyone know of any examples of this, or up-to-date libraries for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of [citeproc-php](https://github.com/seboettg/citeproc-php/) answered an issue on GitHub with some details:

```
<?php
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \AcademicPuma\CiteProc\CiteProc;
$bibliographyStyleName = 'apa';
$lang = "en-US";
$csl = CiteProc::loadStyleSheet($bibliographyStyleName);
$citeProc = new CiteProc($csl, $lang);
$file = file_get_contents("citations.json");

$data = json_decode($file);
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($data as $item) {
   echo "<li>".$citeProc->render($item)."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

And this works as expected with a sample [citations.json](https://bitbucket.org/fbennett/citeproc-js/src/2b552c68ca2a891d3869ebdfa5167115cc5e546f/demo/citations.json?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) from citeproc-js.